# Convert string Column to DateTime Column in DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datable took it from an Excel with the format of the date time as follow **dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm**, this field is a string type in the DataTable i would like to convert it to DateTime in order to be sorted.

I try add a column of type DateTime and parse the string to DateTime but the parse is failing. The first column has the string type of the dates, and i add the column number 9 as DateTime type.

**Here is my code**

```
    private void loadExcelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "excel|*.xlsx";
            openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            this.pathExcel = openFileDialog.FileName;
            DataTable aux = Excel.ExcelToDataTable(this.pathExcel);
            this.openExcelDT = AddDateColumn(aux);
            this.openExcelDT.DefaultView.Sort = "Date asc";
            OpenExcelBinding();
        }
        catch
        {
            
        }
    }

    private void OpenExcelBinding()
    {
        this.openExcelBind.DataSource = this.openExcelDT;
        this.openExcelDGV.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        this.openExcelDGV.DataSource = this.openExcelBind;
        this.openExcelDGV.Refresh();
    }

    private DataTable AddDateColumn(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            string format = "\\\"dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm\\\"";
            DateTime date;
            string s = row[0].ToString();
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                      DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            {
                row[9] = date;
            }
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Comment: Why the format variable has extra double quotes and back slash? `string format = "dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm"` didn't work?

Comment: Row[0] holds a string, row[9] is the new column of datetime type.

Comment: Yes that was the error string format = "dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm";

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
string format = "\\\"dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm\\\"";
DateTime date;
string s = row[0].ToString(format);
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    row[9] = date;
}
```